# Does Jet/ACE use indexes with a LIKE BeginsWith query?

Tags: ms-access, jet, ms-jet-ace

I remember reading somewhere to avoid the LIKE operator in Jet SQL because it will not take advantage of indexes on a column.  So a long time ago I started writing "begins with" queries like this:

```
WHERE MyColumn BETWEEN "SomeText" AND "SomeTextZZZ"
```

As long as there is an index on the MyColumn column, the BETWEEN will take advantage of that index.  I'm starting to question my ways now.  The BETWEEN approach has never really let me down but it feels kludgy.

I can understand why a "contains" query can't use an index:

```
WHERE MyColumn LIKE "*SomeText*"
```

But it seems like using an index on a "begins with" query:

```
WHERE MyColumn LIKE "SomeText*"
```

is such an obvious optimization that the Jet/ACE team would have implemented it.

Can anyone provide ***documentation*** or ***benchmarking proof*** to settle this question one way or another?

Comment: I've always assumed it uses the index. It does appear to be faster than "contains" or "ends with" criteria, so I've always assumed that means that it's somehow using the index. I can't find anything about it in the Jet 3.5 Database Engine Programmer's Guide (the only documentation ever published for Jet).

Comment: updated my answer for access 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SHOWPLAN.OUT`](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/5064388) file to analyse the execution plan of a query. I will submit a test when I am able to.

**Edit:**

Results for your queries on Access 2003:

```
BETWEEN:
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
      using index 'FullName'
      for expression "FullName Between "S" And "SZZZ""

LIKE (begins with):
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
      using index 'FullName'
      for expression "FullName Like "S*""

LIKE (contains):
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
      by scanning
      testing expression "FullName Like "*S*""

LIKE (ends with):
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
      by scanning
      testing expression "FullName Like "*S""
```

So exactly the same pre-ACE.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @cularis for the JETSHOWPLAN idea.  I feel a bit silly for not thinking of it myself.  Here are the results in Access 2007:

```
BETWEEN:
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
    using index 'FullName'
    for expression "Vendors.FullName Between "S" And "SZZZ""

LIKE (begins with):
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
    using index 'FullName'
    for expression "Vendors.FullName Like "S*""

LIKE (contains):
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
    by scanning
    testing expression "Vendors.FullName Like "*S*""

LIKE (ends with):
01) Restrict rows of table Vendors
    by scanning
    testing expression "Vendors.FullName Like "*S""
```

As you can see from the excerpts of my showplan.out file, the kludgy BETWEEN and LIKE (begins with) both make use of the index.  This contrasts with the LIKE (contains) and LIKE (ends with) which are filtered by *scanning* the table (ie, checking each row one at a time).

When I get back to my copy of Access 2002 on Monday, I'll re-run the test on the pre-ACE Jet engine (though I would expect similar results, especially based on @David's experience in his comment to my original question).